# window.focus() not working with firefox driver with augment window

Tags: firefox, window, focus, webdriver

While setting the property `dom.disable_window_flip` to false, able to enable the option "Raise or Lower windows" for the main window in Firefox. But, for the augmenter window that option is not getting enabled and when I execute window.focus on the main window augmenter window is not going to background.

```java
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("dom.disable_window_flip",false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.focus()");
```